# Rename file with EasyAdmin (Symfony6)

Tags: php, easyadmin, symfony6

I have a CRUD controller to add an item in my database:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            TextField::new('title')->setLabel("Titre"),
            TextField::new("directed_by")->setLabel("Réalisateur"),
            DateTimeField::new("date_release")->setLabel("Date de sortie"),
            DateTimeField::new('date_created')->setLabel("Date de création de fiche")
                ->setFormTypeOption("data", new \DateTime("now")),
            ImageField::new("images")->setUploadDir("public/img/films/")
        ];
    }
```

With EasyAdmin, It's possible to rename the file with the title name and create a folder with the same name ?

Thanks.